# View all allowed ports whether in firewalld or iptables

Tags: centos

How can I view the full list of all allowed ports and blocked ports in centos? And I particularly mean all ports and not only those that are in use certain processes. In other words, I am not interested in knowing what process is listening to what ports and I only and only want to know what ports are allowed and not allowed.

Comment: You should not use both iptables and firewalld. It's either the one or the other. Else, it can become messy.

Comment: @Krackout: I know, I'm using a VPS which is pretty messed up and I wanna find why a port does not work in there

Answer (score 0):

`iptables-save` shows the full set of current active firewall rules and default policies. From the output you can deduce what is the current set of allowed / disallowed ports on the system.